# Is there a way to handle pin/unpin events devexpress LayoutPanel

Tags: wpf, events, event-handling, devexpress

I have some LayoutPanels inside a LayoutGroup. I need to handle the pin/unpin events so that I can check/uncheck a checkbox control somewhere in the UI. I tried something like :

```
 <dxd:LayoutPanel x:Name="OverviewPanel"
                             ItemWidth="200"
                             Caption="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowResources}, Path=Resource.Overview}"
                             ShowCloseButton="False"
                             dxd:DockLayoutManager.DockItemCollapsed="OverviewPanel_DockItemCollapsed"
                             AllowDrag="False"
                             AllowFloat="False"
                             AllowContextMenu="False"
                             Padding="1"
                             dxd:AutoHideGroup.AutoHideType="Left"
                             >
                    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" />
                </dxd:LayoutPanel>
```

and in code behind:

```
  private void OverviewPanel_DockItemCollapsed(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.Base.DockItemCollapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        cOverview.IsChecked = false;
    }
```

This didn't work.

The parent of the LayoutGroup is another LayoutGroup and all of them are inside a DockLayoutManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DockLayoutManager.DockOperationCompleted](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_DockOperationCompletedtopic) event:

XAML Markup:

```
<dxd:DockLayoutManager 
    DockOperationCompleted="DockLayoutManager_DockOperationCompleted"
    >
    ...
</dxd:DockLayoutManager>
```

Code-Behind:

```
void DockLayoutManager_DockOperationCompleted(object sender, DockOperationCompletedEventArgs e) {
    switch(e.DockOperation) {
        case DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.DockOperation.Hide:
            // dock panel hidden to auto-hide tray(pinned)
            break;
        case DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.DockOperation.Dock:
            // dock panel docked to layout (e.g. unpinned from auto-hide tray)
            break;
    }
}
```

Related help-article: [Auto-Hide Groups](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6827).